# Uiwebview makes app crash

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, crash

I have a uiwebview in a nib file. Not connected to any outlets. Nowhere in my project have I done any thing with threads myself and also in the nib file are 2 uilabels. With the uiwebview in the nib the app crashes when the nib is loaded onto the screen if I delete the webview then the 2 uilabels appear as expected. This is the erro I get

```
Bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x9b39800: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to call [webView stopLoading] before removing it?